# getting null point exception while converting file to Base64

Tags: android, base64, android-image

I'm going to convert file to base64 so I send file and convert it to bitmap and when i want to compress it, it give me error null point exception 
this is what everything that i did.

```
 public static String getFileToByte(String path){
        Bitmap bm = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        byte[] b = null;
        String encodeString = null;
        try{
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            b = baos.toByteArray();
            encodeString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encodeString;
    }
```

I got error on this error:

```
 bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
```

and pass:

```
getFileToByte(image.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: `getFileToByte`. That looks like a wrong function name considering that you convert to a base64 string.

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert the file to a bitmap first. Your bitmap is null as there is not enough memory to construct a bitmap for that image file with big resolution.

Instead you should directly base64 encode the bytes of the file.

Then your code is the same for all kind of files too.